# Are there SE sites about animals?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation

Is there a SE site for animals? I'm interested in this, and was wondering if there is one/if there's an Area51 for it.

Comment: [I'm not sure if it would get much support.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/1339987)

Comment: @djechlin Ah, that was my first thought too. Beat me by like 30 seconds.

Comment: Did you try [searching Area 51 for "animals"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=animals)?

Comment: Your title is a little ambiguous.

Comment: How do they type?

Comment: Technically humans are animals, so the question "Is there a SE site for animals" *technically* can be answered as "Yes, all of the sites are for animals" :P

Comment: @Doorknob :P You win this round

Comment: I just failed at editing that title. Don't look at the edit history, please

Comment: Do you mean Pets?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  [Search](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=animals) reveals there are currently pets, animal rights, biology, and I guess origami kind of counts.  Perplexed you knew of Area 51 but didn't do a search on it :/